# Display image from Graphviz without creating an intermediate file?

Tags: command-line, graphviz

I would like to display a graph without writing a file first.

Suppose I have a command `foo` that produces this on standard out:

```
digraph foogrph {
   a -> b;
   a -> c;
}
```

What I would like to do is pipe `foo` into `dot` and then pipe the results into a command that will display the image in a graphical environment.

```
foo | dot -Tpng | <display command>
```

I have found a workaround that involves temporary files. In OSX, I can do the following:

```
foo | dot -Tpng > temp && open temp
```

But I still have to remove the file from the filesystem.

How can I display an image that is being written to standard out?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

With ImageMagick's display command, these work on Ubuntu 12.10 (and most likely other OSes, too):

```
dot abac.dot -Tsvg | display
dot abac.dot -Tpng | display
```

SVG has the advantage of smoothly scaling with the window (if that's what you want).

Comment: I had to recompile imagemagick on OSX to use X11, I have display working now, but it doesn't read from a pipe correctly. I found a workaround though: `display <(echo 'digraph { a->b; b->c; c->d; }' | dot -Tpng)`

Comment: Another option is to use `dotty`, examples [here at the git wiki](https://git.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Aliases#Use_graphviz_for_display)

Comment: Also the `imgcat` script that works with iTerm can display the image directly at the terminal, it's pretty sweet :)

Answer (score 3):

On OSX & iTerm2, you can do the following (assuming [imgcat](https://www.iterm2.com/documentation-images.html) is installed)

```
dot abac.dot -Tpng | imgcat
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

On Linux you can also just use `-Tx11:cairo` to display a direct X11 window.

Comment: I tried this and this just produced a big white blank window.

Comment: okay but how can you display the graph without using a file ?

Answer (score 1):

To complete the accepted answer (which is totally OK), if one want to also avoid using a `.dot` file :

`echo 'digraph { a -> b }' | dot -Tpng | display`

(this is for linux only, also I first tried `eog` that doesn't seem accepting pngs through pipes)

Adapted from rom the [documentation](https://www.graphviz.org/doc/info/command.html) of graphviz command line usage.